# PATCH/POST 404 =? (Mailchimp API 3.0 + Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp)

Tags: google-apps-script, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm not a programmer... **So, what's wrong Here?** Why this 404 error?

***How to upsert new members in Mailchimp via API 3.0 + Google Apps Script?***

```js
  // URL and params for the Mailchimp API
  var root = 'https://'+ mc_api_key.split('-')[1] +'.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0';
  var api = '/lists/' + mc_list_id + '/members/' + mc_user_id + '';//
  var params = {"headers": {"authorization": 'apikey '+ mc_api_key}};

  var payload = {
  "email_address": email,
  "merge_fields": { // this are Google Forms onsubmit() fields 
    "EMAIL": email,
    "FNAME": nome,
    "LNAME": sobrenome,
    "PERSONA": persona
     },
  };


  var options = {"headers":{ "Authorization":"apilkey " + mc_api_key},
                 "method":"PATCH",
                 "Content-Type":"application/json",
                 "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
                 "payload": JSON.stringify(payload) }; 


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(root+api,options);
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();
 Logger.log(rc);

}
```

There's a bunch of HTML just to explain it's a 404 error.

Comment: And the api_keys and list_id are for sure correct. The MD5 hash is also correct (from lowercase email) etc... I guess there's something wrong in the method or payload... but I have no idea... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When everything else has failed, [read the doc](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/) :)

It says URL is:

```
https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/...
```

You are using this:

```
https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/lists/{list_id}/...
```

That would explain the 404.

(Everything under `api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/` is the [*description of the API*](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#json-schema), not the API itself)

Comment: LOL... That's why I'm a beginner!.. Thank you and Sorry for this dumb question!

Comment: No problem, whatever the reason that misled you to use the wrong URL (bad tutorial, confusing doc... no matter), maybe someone will make the same mistake and will find this. Which is why it's important that you verify if the suggested change actually works for you, and in that case mark this answer as accepted. More importantly even: if it does not work for you, let it be known! (a wrong answer is worse than a correct unaccepted answer). Also consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), for your next questions.